# Why does Data.Time.Clock.DiffTime have a Fractional instance?

Tags: haskell

The [docs for Fractional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) state:

> Fractional numbers, supporting real division.
>
> The Haskell Report defines no laws for Fractional. However, '(+)' and '(*)' are customarily expected to define a division ring and have the following properties:
>
> recip gives the multiplicative inverse
> `x * recip x = recip x * x = fromInteger 1`

But [Data.Time.Clock.DiffTime](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.3/docs/html/libraries/time-1.8.0.2/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:DiffTime) seems to be implemented as the number of picoseconds thus:

```
> import Data.Time
>((picosecondsToDiffTime 10) / 3) * 3 -- real division ?
0.000000000009s
>>recip 3 * (3 :: DiffTime) -- customarily expected to be 1
0.999999999999s
```

Is this widely accepted or should it be reported?

**Update**

After some discussion it is clear that the question should have been 2 questions:

1. Why do most [Fractional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) instances not satisfy the laws that they are expected to satisfy? (the docs would suggest that Fractional is reserved for types isomorphic to [Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio))
2. Why does Haskell use the same type to express all kinds of quantities related to time (point in time, duration, ratio) which has instances that don't make sense with most of them? (as pointed out by @leftaroundabout)

Comment: I mean, the documentation you linked explicitly states `DiffTime` "*[...] has a precision of 10^-12 s*", so I'm not sure what results you expected instead.

Comment: "*Is this widely accepted or should it be reported?*" Wait until you discover floating-point numbers.

Comment: I expected Fractional to be reserved for types isomorphic to [Ratio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#t:Ratio). That's what I expected from the phrase "..., supporting real division." as opposed to floating-point division.

Comment: That's "real division" as opposed to integer division, for types that can represent (approximations to) the set of real numbers.

Comment: Also isn't this exactly what the `recip`-involving law states?

Comment: Any library involving floating point numbers will tell you don't use the equality operator on the values. And here we're stating a requirement on the values involving the equality operator.

Comment: @melpomene this behaviour is much more dubious than the behaviour of floating-point numbers (which actually behave for the most part quite sensible as far as _physics calculations on real numbers_ are concerned. Just computer scientists can' t seem to get to terms with FP,  but most of the confusion is avoided if you just _never assume that two FP numbers are equal_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense that `DiffTime` is even an instance of `Num`, because physically speaking, if you multiply two times you don't get a time (but rather a square-time – seldom talked about this way but it does crop up in some physics calculations).

What does make lots of sense is to want to divide times by each other, which is evidently the reason why the `Fractional` instance was added. The result of that, again, isn't a time but a *real number*. And you can *scale* times by other real numbers. There is a class that expresses this in a mathematically/physically perfectly clean way, though unfortunately not in the base package: [VectorSpace](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#t:VectorSpace). The instance should be something like this:

```
instance VectorSpace DiffTime where
  type Scalar DiffTime = Double
  a *^ t = picosecondsToDiffTime . round
            $ a * fromIntegral (diffTimeToPicoseconds t)
```

Here, it's completely unambiguous what you mean when you multiply a time by, say, `3`: thrice that time. You can also divide a time by a number then, using [`^/`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.15/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html#v:-94--47-) (which just multiplies by a reciprocal).

What you still can't do with `VectorSpace` is dividing times *to get their ratio*; that is supported by [`OneDimensional`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-vector-spaces-0.1.5.0/docs/Data-VectorSpace-Free.html#t:OneDimensional) from my `free-vector-spaces` package or by [`DivisibleSpace.C` from `numeric-prelude`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.3.1/docs/Algebra-DivisibleSpace.html#v:-60--47--62-). Both aren't very widely used though.

Unfortunately, the `time` library has preferred to give much more bug-prone `Num` and `Fractional` instances, which just assume that *one second* is the conceptual-fundamental time unit. Quite weird. The [thyme library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thyme-0.3.5.5/docs/Data-Thyme-Clock.html), which is generally much better thought through in terms of type safety, does implement vector space instances. (Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be much maintained anymore, but I'd still use it.)

Comment: Actually given that [POSIXTime](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.2/docs/Data-Time-Clock-POSIX.html) is a synonym of DiffTime I'm not sure getting the ratio of two of them makes much sense either. I would expect a type for time to allow only equality comparison (to identify events by the time when they happened) and checking for ordering (causality of events).

Comment: @fghibellini well, that's another problem; absolute times should be separate types from relative ones (and offer not `VectorSpace` but [`AffineSpace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour-2.3.4/docs/Data-Colour.html#t:AffineSpace) instances).